# Combine two MySQL select statements together

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-8.0

I have a small table in MySQL 8 with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `payload` json NOT NULL,
  `type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `market_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

and some data

[image]

The type_id=7 has always a referenceId a value that is equal to some market_id.

I am getting my results in two steps

> select json_extract(payload, '$.referenceId')  from new_table  where
>   type_id=7

that returns the market_ids that are stored in a payload (10000)

and after that

> select id from new_table where market_id=10000 and type_id=2

that finally gives me all the ids that have type_id=2 and the market_id is referred in some other record.

I would like to do this in one and not two steps. How can I do this? I want all the market_ids of type_id 2, where the market_id is in the json payload where the market_id is 7

Here are some values:

INSERT INTO `` (`id`,`payload`,`type_id`,`market_id`) VALUES (1,'{\"Value\": 20}',2,10000);
INSERT INTO `` (`id`,`payload`,`type_id`,`market_id`) VALUES (2,'{\"Value\": 20}',3,10001);
INSERT INTO `` (`id`,`payload`,`type_id`,`market_id`) VALUES (3,'{\"Value\": 30}',4,10002);
INSERT INTO `` (`id`,`payload`,`type_id`,`market_id`) VALUES (4,'{\"Value\": 120}',12,10003);
INSERT INTO `` (`id`,`payload`,`type_id`,`market_id`) VALUES (5,'{\"Value\": 201}',2,10004);
INSERT INTO `` (`id`,`payload`,`type_id`,`market_id`) VALUES (6,'{\"Value\": 20, \"referenceId\": 10000}',7,10005);
INSERT INTO `` (`id`,`payload`,`type_id`,`market_id`) VALUES (7,'{\"Value\": 201}',3,10000);
INSERT INTO `` (`id`,`payload`,`type_id`,`market_id`) VALUES (8,'{\"Value\": 20, \"referenceId\": 10004}',7,10008);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to do this in one and not two steps.

You can do that with a subquery.

```
select
    id
from
    new_table
where 
    market_id = (
        select json_extract(payload, '$.referenceId')
        from   new_table
        where  type_id = 7
    )
    and type_id = 2
```

See DB Fiddle for an interactive demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qHjmGSzwCgRSytW4wuhK1N/0

Comment: works for that data, but if I add this line INSERT INTO `` (`id`,`payload`,`type_id`,`market_id`) VALUES (8,'{\"Value\": 20, \"referenceId\": 10004}',7,10008); I am getting back OK and no data

Comment: `where market_id IN (...)` - you should have been able to figure that out yourself :)

Comment: true, sad but true.

Comment: No worries. I anticipated the question.